# How to apply filter on click of dropdown in sencha

Tags: sencha-touch

I have two drop downs to book an appointment. One is "from time" and another is "to time".  In the drop downs there are slots for eg. 9 am to 11 am and 1 pm to 3 pm , so when i select a 1st slot that is 9 am to 11 pm , then in the "to time" drop down i can only see available timing to book a appointment in 1st slot ie 9.15 , 10.15 etc. So now i have selected an appointment from = 9.15  to = 10.15. Now i click on "from time" drop down i am able to see all available slots and i don't make any changes here but when i click on " to time" drop down i am able to see all slot timings which is unexpected as i didn't make any changes, so expected behavior should be filter should be applied as per "from time" drop down even if i make any changes or not.

Following is my code

```
{
        xtype: 'selectfield',
        name: 'fromTime',
        id: 'fromTime',
        placeHolder: 'Select From Time',
        label: 'From:',
        labelWrap: true,
        store: 'DoctorLocationTimes',
        displayField: 'fromTime',
        valueField: 'fromTime',
        listeners: [
        {
          event: 'change',
          fn: function(){
            var fromTime, timeStore, index, record, docLocationid;            
            fromTime = Ext.getCmp('fromTime').getValue();
            timeStore = Ext.getStore('DoctorLocationTimes');
            timeStore.clearFilter();
            index= timeStore.find('fromTime', fromTime);
            if(index != -1){
              record = timeStore.getAt(index);
              docLocationid = record.get('docLocationWorkingHourid');
              timeStore.filter('docLocationWorkingHourid',docLocationid);
            }
          }
        },
        {
          event:'focus',
          fn: function(){
            var store = Ext.getStore('DoctorLocationTimes');
            store.clearFilter();
          }
        }
      ]
  }
```

As you can see i am applying filter on the basis of "from time" id .and again i am removing filter because again in from time i want to display all slots in "from time" drop down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the answer.its working now.

```
{
        xtype: 'selectfield',
        name: 'toTime',
        id: 'toTime',
        placeHolder: 'Select To Time',
        label: 'To:',
        labelWrap: true,
        store: 'DoctorLocationTimes',
        displayField: 'toTime',
        valueField: 'toTime',
        listeners: [
        {
          event:'focus',
          fn: function(){
            var fromTime, timeStore, index, record, docLocationid;            
            fromTime = Ext.getCmp('fromTime').getValue();
            timeStore = Ext.getStore('DoctorLocationTimes');
            timeStore.clearFilter();
            index= timeStore.find('fromTime', fromTime);
            if(index != -1){
              record = timeStore.getAt(index);
              docLocationid = record.get('docLocationWorkingHourid');
              timeStore.filter('docLocationWorkingHourid',docLocationid);
            }
          }
        }]
      }
```

I found that after applying filter on focus event of "to time" drop downs its working as expected.